Constructing a graph from columns of an array or table
I have a data table that I imported into WM (I hope I did it correctly):
u = ImportString[
   StringReplace[
    Import["C:\\Users\\79533\\Desktop\\Chopper\\voltage.csv", 
     "Text"], {"," -> ".", ";" -> ","}], "CSV", 
   "NumberPoint" -> "."][[19 ;;]]

The imported table has three columns:
{{-9.96*10^-6, -8., 8.}, {-9.6*10^-6, -8., 16.}, {-9.2*10^-6, -8., 
  16.}, {-8.8*10^-6, -8., 16.}, {-8.4*10^-6, -8., 
  16.}, {-8.*10^-6, -8., 16.}, {-7.6*10^-6, -8., 
  16.}, {-7.2*10^-6, -8., 16.}, {-6.8*10^-6, -8., 
  16.}, {-6.4*10^-6, -8., 16.}, {-6.*10^-6, -8., 
  16.}, {-5.6*10^-6, -8., 16.}}

How can I plot the data in the second and third column versus the data in the first column?

Do you want something like: ListPlot[{u[[All, {1, 2}]], u[[All, {1, 3}]]}]?

You may use "DataRange" like: ListPlot[{d[[All, 2]], d[[All, 3]]}, DataRange -> MinMax@d[[All, 1]]]
